# Creating a secure login

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a login form and I want to know if I'm missing or over-looking anything. Normally how I go about doing this is:

- Grab username/password form user and test it to see if meets basic syntax requirements.
- Use Ajax to send the username and password to php using escape string to prevent sql injections
- once I get the password on php I hash the password and compare it with the database to see if there is a match. If there is a match I would return a URL to the next page and set the username in session and create a session variable to indicate that I'm logged in
- Once I land on the next page I run a function to see if the session variable for login is set and if it is will continue, else re-direct the user to the login page. I'm not sure where to put that code to check if user is logged in or not. I normally put it outside the of the document ready, but it will allows the user to see a hint of the page before they're re-directed.

Comment: What you're asking for is off-topic for **many** reasons. I think that now would be a good time for you to go over the help area if you haven't already https://stackoverflow.com/help and the related links inside it. Read through that and you'll see how things work here on Stack Overflow. It will give you a good idea as to how to formulate a good question, to see what can and should not be asked, as well as what is expected from you. This was made and put into place in order to help (you) have a better and positive experience here on Stack Overflow, which is what everybody wants and aims for.

Comment: You left out that this should happen over **https**, for sure.

Comment: Also, rather than the user getting to a page, and then that page checking to see if they are logged in, when the user requests a page that requires them to be logged in, the server should check their status.  If they are not logged in, the server (php in this case) should redirect them to the login, not the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is best suited for `securitystackexchange`, but here a few hints:

1) You need all your requests go over ssl.
2) ajax and javascript have nothing to do with sql injection. You have to use prepared statements to query the database to avoid sql injection.
3) escaping html (if you were actually refering to that, should be done before putting html on the screen)
4) You should protect your forms including the login form agains csrf attacks. You can do this with a nonce.
6) After a successful login you should create a new session.